# LLVM automatic C++ linking

Tags: c++, llvm

In some of the LLVM tutorials I'm seen where it's fairly easy to bind C function into a custom language based on LLVM. LLVM hands the programmer a pointer to the function that can be then be mixed in with the code being generated by LLVM.

What's the best method to do this with C++ libraries. Let's say I have a fairly complex library like Qt or Boost that I want to bind to my custom language. Do I need to create a stub library (like Python or Lua require), or does LLVM offer some sort of foreign function interface (FFI)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In my LLVM code, I create `extern "C"` wrapper functions for this, and insert LLVM function declarations into the module in order to call them. Then, a good way to make LLVM know about the functions is not to let it use `dlopen` and search for the function name in the executing binary (this is a pain in the ass, since the function names need to be in the `.dynsym` section, and it is slow too), but to do the mapping manually, using [ExecutionEngine::addGlobalMapping](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ExecutionEngine.html#a805704b52a327cc6b37aebf9cba14169).

Just get the `llvm::Function*` of that declaration and the address of the function as given in C++ by `&functionname` converted to `void*` and pass these two things along to LLVM. The JIT executing your stuff will then know where to find the function.

For example, if you wanted to wrap `QString` you could create several functions that create, destroy and call functions of such an object

```
extern "C" void createQString(void *p, char const*v) {
  new (p) QString(v); // placement-new
}

extern "C" int32_t countQString(void *p) {
  QString *q = static_cast<QString*>(p);
  return q->count();
}

extern "C" void destroyQString(void *p) {
  QString *q = static_cast<QString*>(p);
  q->~QString();
}
```

And create proper declarations and a mapping. Then you can `call` these functions, passing along a memory region suitably aligned and sized for `QString` (possibly `alloca`'ed) and a `i8*` pointing to the C string data for initialization.

Comment: Gets the answer for providing concise code examples. Thanks! exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

If you compile some code in C++ and some in another language to LLVM bitcode, it should be perfectly possible to link these together and let one call the other... in theory.

In practice, you will need glue code to convert between the different language's types (e.g. there is no equivalent to a Python string in C++ unless you use CPython, so for `void reverse(std::string s)` to be callable with a `str` you need a conversion - worse, the whole object model is very different). And Qt specifically has a lot of magic that may require much more effort to expose after compilations. Also, there may be further potential problems I'm not aware of.

And even if that works, it's potentially very ugly to use. There are still `get*` and `set*` functions all over PyQt despite Python's very convenient descriptors - and much effort went into PyQt, they didn't just create some stubs.